# “Tug of war” binary orbit model

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, inertial-frames

Is there in theory any support for this model?

As object B moves, object A continues (because of inertia) in tangent of orbit before B moved. Gravitational pull to B, then pulls A back into orbit, and as B moves more, the “tug of war” repeats.

B also adjusts path to movement of A, in similar manner.

The momentum and gravitational pull balance out in a wave-like orbital path. The illustration below is greatly exaggerated, actual periodic adjustments would be barely measurable, high resolution measurements needed to observe it.

[image]

As object B moves, the acceleration on object A has to overcome the inertia of object A. If that is not completely balanced, it seems like there should be oscillations. Another way to put it, while the vector for gravitational force changes, inertia of the objects remains the same.

Comment: Yes, if you believe in the concept of Planck time and Planck length since there's no such thing as a perfect ellipse with those concepts. However, the effects would be, by definition, at the limit of our ability to measure them.

Comment: "[T]he concept[s] of Planck time and Planck length" do not neccessarily imply discretness of space and time. They never have. They *allow* it, but trying to impose it get's you all the usual conflict with Noether's theorem.

Answer (score 3):

To be blunt:

## No.

Planetary orbits were worked out by Kepler and Newton about 300 years ago. The equations of motion can be solved exactly and they do not have *any* such oscillatory motion. (This is because the effects of inertia and gravitational interaction happen simultaneously, over infinitesimally-small time increments, in ways that can be described rigorously using calculus.) Moreover, planetary motion can be tracked with huge precision (both from direct astronomical observations and, since the 60s, with radar) and it shows no such motion.

Instead of idle wonderings, maybe it would be better to pick up a textbook instead?

Comment: Planetary orbits are *not* binary systems, in the context here. Yes, sun has minor reflex orbit from planets, but not how a binary system is defined.

Comment: The effect would, obviously, not be accounted for in equations for planetary motions, as it would be small. That is mentioned in the question. You use the phrase "infinitesimally-small time increments", infinitesimally can be used as both "very small" and "infinitely small", the former does imply periodic adjustments.

Comment: @Duplex Are you saying that you don't believe that Newton's theory is correct? (If so, please refer to [this guidance thread](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4538).)

Comment: No need for authoritarianism. As I said, infinitesimally can be used in two ways. In one ways, it means "infinitely small", in that case there is no incremental adjustments as there are no increments. In the other way, it means "very small", meaning there are periodic adjustments. You contradict yourself, either way.

Comment: 'Infinitesimal' is a technical term and there is no ambiguity about its meaning. There are no oscillations. Deal with it.

Comment: When infinitely small, there are no increments. If there are increments, there are oscillations.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is **no**, as said by Emilio Pisanty. Your model is not based on Newtonian Mechanics but in [Cartoon Physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartoon_physics). You are imposing to nature your own categorization of different physical elements which are really there (like inertia and the gravitational pull), but you are suspending one and the other in an alternate fashion without any reason to do so except from the fact it makes the narration more structurally confortable for you. Nature doesn't care about how we think about it. Nature doesn't care if we first invoke inertia and then gravity just because in that way our brains can understand the full picture in linear steps. For nature these two things (gravity and inertia) are going on at the same time, continuosly.

When Emilio Pisanty says "infinitely small" he's referring to such small increments that they have indeed no size at all (this is just a mathematical tool to get to the point about the continuity of obital motion in an effort to approximate your model to the true orbital mechanics by shrinking the steps of your reasoning down to nothing).

I said cartoon physics because your model is based exactly on the same principles that drive the Coyote to be floating for a few moments, suspended in mid air above the cliff (gravity turned of and inertia still going), just until he realizes about the situation and the fall begins (suddenly inertia turns off and gravity kicks in).

Also, from the comments on Emilio's answer, you seem to think that Kepler laws are just a set of rules that apply only to the Solar System but not elsewere. Kepler laws are a particular form of the [two-body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem) in Newtonian mechanics. There is no reason to categorically separate the Solar System from a Binary System in their mechanical nature. Again, mechanics is a coherent universal framework, not a set of independent rules that cease to apply in different scenarios and are only usefull for specific human-tagged physical systems.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102222/discussion-on-answer-by-swike-tug-of-war-binary-orbit-model).